# Issue with php memcache fetching the value with 'true'

Tags: php, memcached

When I store the value of the *memcache* key "show-errors" with value true
using the following method call it returns success (ie. true) saying it has set.

```
$memcacheObj->set("show-errors", true);
```

But when I get the key using the following method call I get 1 instead of true

```
$memcacheObj->get($key);
```

Can anyone help me with this. I need to get the value exactly as stored in the *memcache*.

I have cross verified that my memcached server is running on my local system using the following method it returns true.

```
$this->cacheObj->connect('127.0.0.1', '11211');
```

Comment: Afaik, memcached save the values serialized, and the serialize value of `TRUE` is `1`

Comment: @Sal00m, is there a way to get the desserialized value after getting the result

Comment: You can use `filter_var` this way: `filter_var($memcacheObj->get($key), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);` it should return `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike what you've been told in the comments, the unserialized value of a serialized boolean TRUE is still true.
It seems the problem is not your memcache but your check.

Try checking weather your variable is `=== true` rather than printing it out and you'll see.

Here's [some example code](https://eval.in/143081) to show you how this works:

```
<?php
$peter = true;
$serPeter = serialize($peter);

$unserPeter = unserialize($serPeter);
if($unserPeter === TRUE) {
  echo 'TRUE';
}
elseif($unserPeter === 1) {
  echo '1';
}
else {
  echo '$unserPeter is : ('.$unserPeter.')';
}
```